# How do I format the floats in specific manner?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two floats numbers as a result for a python code.

```
30.00 
3995.0081
```

I want to format them in such a way they have a total equal no. of digits(example 11). For example the above two digits will produce the following result.

```
30.000000000
3995.0081000
```

If you notice, the no. of degits after the decimal point in these two are unequal yet total no. of degits are the same.
I tried to use the following method

```
print('{0:11.9f}'.format(number))
```

But it produces the following result which is wrong.

```
30.000000000
3995.008100000
```

Is there any method or function which can produce the desired result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this is for display purposes only, so a string would allow for this.  The two data examples you gave both already had decimals contained within, but I don't know if that'd always be the case.  If not, there would a bit extra logic; but I think this would get things started.

```
def sizer(input_number):
    output = str(float(input_number)) + '0' * 11  # or some number in excess of the desired number of digits 
    output = output[0:12]  # based on the example of 11 desired digits
    print(output)

sizer(30.00)
sizer(3995.0081)
```

Comment: Nice answer. With `str(float(input_number))` you can also cover the case where the argument is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 6
Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
```

> Decimal('0.142857')

```
getcontext().prec = 28
Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
```

> Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom print function that adapts the formating string:

```
def custom_print(n, ndig=11):
    spec = '{0}.{1}f'.format(ndig, ndig -1 - len(str(n).split('.')[0]))
    print(n.__format__(spec))

custom_print(a)
custom_print(b)

>>>30.00000000
>>>3995.008100
```

where `ndig -1 - len(str(n).split('.')[0]` is the number of digits after the decimal point.